# How can I use featherlight.gallery.js to display not only photos but some html content in modal, too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gallery, featherlight.js

Is it possible to use https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/ featherlight.js and featherlight.gallery.js to display some custom HTML in the gallery? For example, photo with a form for commenting.

I have tried in such way:

```
<a class="gallery" href="some.html">
    Some text
</a>
<a class="gallery" href="another.html">
    Some another text
</a>
```

and

```
$('a.gallery').featherlightGallery();
```

And when I click next slide button it shows next image and form, but it returns js error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
at getStyles (jquery-latest.js:6118)
at curCSS (jquery-latest.js:6125)
at Function.css (jquery-latest.js:6718)
at Text.isHidden (jquery-latest.js:4098)
at jquery-latest.js:2647
at Function.grep (jquery-latest.js:482)
at winnow (jquery-latest.js:2645)
at jQuery.fn.init.filter (jquery-latest.js:2713)
at jQuery.fn.init.fadeTo (jquery-latest.js:7451)
at Array.<anonymous> (featherlight.gallery.min.js:7)
```

But for when I click for the second time - it simply returns an error and nothing appear.

So, is it possible? Or can you advise me some another js gallery for this solution?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can. In [this page](http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/gallery.html) the second gallery (second row) has a slide that's only HTML.